# How to monitor Network Traffic at a particual port number let "8443"

Tags: networking, traffic

To measure network traffic, I explored various ways like ntop, tcpdump, iftop, bmon. But, Exact network traffic for port number 8443 is not resulted by any of them.

Please suggest how to measure network traffic at a specific port in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) is a nice GUI tool for network analysis. You can filter the packets according to port number for your purpose. [Steps for installing](https://www.linuxhelp.com/how-to-install-wireshark-2-2-5-on-ubuntu-16-04/)

Comment: Also, `nethogs` http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/nethogs.8.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a program called wireshark that I think should allow you to view traffic for any port.

To install wireshark, click the ubuntu software to your left and search fore wireshark.

or..

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install wireshark 
 sudo apt-get upgrade
```

There is also another program called tshark very similar to wireshark but I believe you would have to install that from source.

```
netstat -a 
sudo netstat -tulpn
```

shows whats going on for them port

Comment: It will be better to add the repository for Wireshark for keeping it up-to-date. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wireshark-dev/stable`